# Does Pivotal Cloud Foundry support MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, pcf

I am currently self-learning on the basics of cloud foundry and i was wondering if Pivotal Cloud Foundry supports MariaDB or can PCF only link to similar databases such as MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: This may help you :
https://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/1-10/

Comment: Thank you Omkar!

Answer (score 0):

PCF does not support mariadb for now but definitely they are going to support in near future....
It supports mysql for now. This should help you: https://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/1-10/